# Visual Studio 2017 github two remotes and sync

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017

I'm just getting started using git in Visual Studio 2017.  I found an open source project I am interested in that I want to contribute to.  Then, in github, I forked the repo for that project, made a small change (directly in github) and created a pull request.  Everything worked as expected.

Then I decided I wanted to use Visual Studio for more extensive work.  So, in VS 2017, I added the original repo and synced it to my local repo (which I had just created).  I then wanted to add my forked repo in github as a second remote.  No problem there, and I now have two remotes.

My local repo and workspace match the original repo for the project.  However, my github repo containing the fork has that one, little change.  I'd like to get that into my local repo and workspace.  However on the sync page it says "no incoming requests".

So at this point I'm stuck.  What do I need to do to make Visual Studio look at my remote repo *as well as* the original one, and sync from both (possibly with conflicts to resolve, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>pull</kbd> and <kbd>fetch</kbd> links on the Sync page should have a <kbd>▼</kbd> button right next to them. This will allow you to pull and fetch from a specific remote. Sync doesn't have this option, it only works on the default remote (and is a bad practice anyway).

[image]

Alternatively, you can go to the branches page and expand the specific remote. Right-click the branch you want and perform a <kbd>fetch</kbd> followed by a <kbd>rebase onto</kbd>. Or <kbd>merge from</kbd>, depending on your desired workflow:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!!